# Why i get the first array item is undefined?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I set a global variable

```
var URL = [];
```

and get the data:

```
casper.then(function () {
    // I get 19 links from this code
    URL = this.evaluate(getURL);
    // I can see i get the first link
    console.log(URL[0] + '***************');
});
```

but after this function my URL[0] shows undefined.

```
// But this URL[0] shows the error that 
casper.thenOpen("'" + URL[0] + "'", function () {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
```

The error like this:

```
[debug] [phantom] opening url: 'undefined', HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=file:///Users/motogod19/PhantomPractice/parse_movie/'undefined', type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail: file:///Users/motogod19/PhantomPractice/parse_movie/'undefined'
```

Why ? I can't figure it out . Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `evaluate` probably doesn't return anything.

Comment: It has data i'm sure. I find the solution , thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call an `async` method. Therefore you need to make sure that you get the `URL`'s value first before calling the next method which need this variable's value. Try this:

```
casper.then(function () {
  // I get 19 links from this code
  URL = this.evaluate(getURL);
  // I can see i get the first link
  console.log(URL[0] + '***************');

  if (!URL[0]) {
    // should handle the condition where url list is empty
    return;
  }

  casper.thenOpen("'" + URL[0] + "'", function () {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks. It solve undefined issue.